# flash video netstream.time always returns '0' on air android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I've tried to reduce this down to just the operative code for this example: (assume 'logo.f4v' is a short video clip in the root of the project, and has been included in the package.)

```
var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connection.connect(null);
var video:Video = new Video(1280, 720);
addChild(video);
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
video.attachNetStream(stream);
stream.play('logo.f4v');
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void    {   trace(stream.time); });
```

So this *should* just drop a video on the stage, then trace the stream's progress as it plays back, one trace per frame. Testing this through the Flash IDE, it traces out the values you'd expect:

> 0
>
> 0.007
>
> 0.046
>
> 0.092
>
> etc.

but running on the android device the progress value doesn't change to reflect playback time:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> etc.

What's the deal? In case it's relevant, this is an ASUS MeMo Pad 10.1, running OS version 4.3 - and the air app is set to use GPU-rendering mode.

Comment: Also, There is issue with volume level on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the NetStream play with MP4 source file and it works great (and the time progress correctly),
Also Its recommended to use StageVideo and MP4 files with Android Air to have the advantage of hardware acceleration this give you better quality and consume less power.

Comment: hmm, weird. what device are you testing on? if I posted source files, would you be willing to try doing a build using the exact stuff I'm using and see if you still get different results?

Comment: i am using Galaxy tab 10.1, ok send your files and i will try.

Comment: I tried it on Flash Builder and it works here is the output:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0.673
0.673
0.673
0.673
0.673
0.833
0.833
1.133
1.1380000000000001
1.1380000000000001
1.5330000000000001
1.6
1.6
1.7
2.067
2.206
2.206
2.206

My Device called Onda (OS 4.0 Air Version 4.0)

Comment: Again matt if you want to got advantage of GPU why don't you use stage  Video it is the component designed for that.
You just need to encode your videos in MP4 (h264/aac) format

Comment: weeeeird. sounds like it might just be an issue on my device?

and I'm not using stageVideo basically for convenience' sake - this has been a quick project, building what was formerly a flash piece into an air app for windows & android, and I want to keep code as consistent between both OSes *and* reuse as much as possible from the previous rev.

hopefully next round we'll have the timeline to do it *right*, but for now we've got to do it *fast*.

Comment: Use this SimpleStageVideo Class found here(https://code.google.com/p/simplestagevideo/downloads/list), it will use the StageVideo if available and swap to old Video object if not available.
this way you still consistent in both mobiles & desktops.
another advantage of stage video the video is much more smooth than old video on mobiles.